# Set increasing value of one column based on value in another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    date
0   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-02
2   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-04
4   2021-01-05
5   2021-01-06
6   2021-01-07
7   2021-01-08
8   2021-01-09
9   2021-01-10
```

I would to add a new column `out` to this df to indicate when a wedding started with the value 0. The rows after the start date should increment while the rows before the start date should decrement. For example, if the wedding started on '2021-01-05', my desired output is this:

```
    date        out
0   2021-01-01  -5
1   2021-01-02  -4
2   2021-01-03  -3
3   2021-01-04  -2
4   2021-01-05  -1
5   2021-01-06   0
6   2021-01-07   1
7   2021-01-08   2
8   2021-01-09   3
9   2021-01-10   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing

```
df['out'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.date) - pd.to_datetime('2021-01-06')).dt.days
Out[20]: 
0   -5
1   -4
2   -3
3   -2
4   -1
5    0
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `date` column doesn't duplicate, you can try

```py
df['time'] = range(len(df))
df['time'] = df['time'] - df.set_index('date').loc['2021-01-06', 'time']
```

```
print(df)

         date  time
0  2021-01-01    -5
1  2021-01-02    -4
2  2021-01-03    -3
3  2021-01-04    -2
4  2021-01-05    -1
5  2021-01-06     0
6  2021-01-07     1
7  2021-01-08     2
8  2021-01-09     3
9  2021-01-10     4
```

Or

```py
df['time'] = df.index.values - df['date'].tolist().index('2021-01-06')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumcount() to get the expected output posted

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Control'] = 1
date_lookback_location = df.loc[df['date'] == '2021-01-06'].index.tolist()[0]
df['time'] = df.sort_values(['date'], ascending=True).groupby(['Control']).cumcount() -date_lookback_location
df[['date', 'time']]
```

Comment: Although this gives the desired output, I don't know exactly how many rows my dataframe contains. Therefore I would like to prevent that I have to manually specify the lowest number (e.g. -5)

Comment: I updated my answer to include a way to dynamically control what the lookback would be. On the "date_lookback_location" you would simply need to put the date you are looking for and then it will take the index value and set the cumcount() back appropriately.